# Is there any reason to use extern "C" on headers without methods?

Tags: c++, c, header-files, extern, extern-c

I frequently come across C header files that contain `extern "C"` guards,
but don't contain any actual functions.  For example:

```
/* b_ptrdiff.h - base type ptrdiff_t definition header */

#ifndef __INCb_ptrdiff_th
#define __INCb_ptrdiff_th

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifndef _PTRDIFF_T
#define _PTRDIFF_T
typedef long ptrdiff_t;
#endif /* _PTRDIFF_T */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* __INCb_ptrdiff_th */
```

I know that `extern "C"` prevents name mangling on functions, but does it also prevent against other interfacing issues on variable and type declarations?

Is the use of `extern "C"` in the example above meaningless in terms of resulting compatibility?

Comment: `extern "C"` does not "prevent" name mangling. It tells the compiler, among other things, to use C-style name mangling.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Some compilers (it's rare) implement name mangling for variables too, not just for functions. In that case, `extern "C"` may be needed.

Some compilers (it's also rare, but required by the standard) implement language linkage for function *types*, not just names, so `typedef void f();` and `extern "C" { typedef void f(); }` declare different types.

Also, some maintainers won't notice the absence of `extern "C"` if they modify the header to add functions.

I recommend you just include it.

Comment: Are you sure that type linkage is *required* by the standard ? If so, why is it so rare ?

Comment: @Quentin Yes, I am sure. However, there is very little demand from users for this feature, so implementations focus on other features that are in higher demand.

Comment: Thank you for acknowledging that "required by the standard" doesn't mean "always available/implemented."

Comment: @Quentin: Personally, I consider function type linkage a C++ anti-feature. For instance, that makes technically impossible to use a pointer to a C++ static member as a C pointer to function. The C++ committee makes a hack for `qsort()` and `bsearch()` and they believe the problem does not exist any more.

Answer (score 9):

No, `extern C` is not needed there, but it may be convenient to have it in all headers to make sure it is not forgotten when a new function is added.